# Geometric control: Given a rotation matrix how can I compute its derivative without knowing the angular velocity of its principal axes?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, rotations, control-theory

I am trying to implement the geometric controller presented in [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2e83/b6f1d6da2694dd029597911599c03b690afc.pdf) in python to control a simulated quadcopter.

First a little background of the general control problem: given a trajectory of the center-of-mass $x \in R^3$ and the direction of the first body axis $b^\rightarrow_{1d} \in R^3$, compute the control inputs $f \in R$ (force) and $M \in R^3$ (moment around each principal axis) to follow this trajectory.

My problem arises in computing the desired control action: in equation 11 the authors use $\Omega_d$, the desired angular velocity.

My question: How do I compute $\Omega_d$?

---

Some more information: $R_d$ is known, and I know that $\dot{R}_d = R_d \cdot \hat{\Omega}_d$.So my question can be formulated as: how do I compute $\dot{R}_d$ given $R_d$?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

$R_dR_d^T = I$

$\dot{R}_dR_d^T +R_d\dot{R}_d^T = 0$

$\dot{R}_d = -R_d\dot{R}_d^TR_d$

I'm not sure how this gets me a step further.

Comment: Use $R R^{\top} = I$

Comment: I assume you know $R_d$ as a function of time, so can't you just take the derivative of $R_d$ with respect to time?

Comment: No, I don't know $R_d(t)$ only $R_d$ at one specific instance

Comment: Then you don't have enough information. Or do you know $R_d$ at a fixed sample time?

Comment: I think the key point is after Eq. 5: "where the hat map $\hat  : R^3 → so(3)$ is defined by the condition that $hat xy=x \times y$ for al lx,y∈$R^3$."